# How to ensure at least one item is selected onItemClick in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view in which I want to ensure atleast one list item should be clicked, what conditions do I need to check on "onItemClick". Again the condition should not go false if I "check" or "uncheck".

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    if(view != null){
                        CheckBox chkboxName = (CheckBox) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.option_image);
                        chkboxName.performClick();
                    }

                }
});
```

Comment: control data with viewholder

Comment: please post your list adapter class